# git log: contributors list since certain tag?

Tags: git, git-log

So I know this awesome script to display the contributors of my repo with their associated number of commits:

```
#!/bin/sh
git log --no-merges "$@" | grep ^Author: | sed 's/ <.*//; s/^Author: //' | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr
```

But now I'm interested in a script that would do exactly the same thing, but only from a certain range of checkpoints (for example: since tag XYZ to master branch HEAD).

How could I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use git log with range of commits:

```
git log sha1..sha2
```

Probably will work for tags too.

Comment: and I can use HEAD too

Answer (score 1):

You should define the range as "commit-ish..commit-ish" in the command. Commit-ish means "commit id or tag name or branch name or HEAD"

Between commits:

```
#!/bin/sh
git log ff46a5..e567a98 --no-merges "$@" | grep ^Author: | sed 's/ <.*//; s/^Author: //' | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr
```

Between tags and branches (labels):

```
#!/bin/sh
git log MyTag..HEAD --no-merges "$@" | grep ^Author: | sed 's/ <.*//; s/^Author: //' | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr
```